# Improving Time Complexity

Tags: c#, time-complexity, big-o

I would appreciate some feedback with regards to Big-O (time-complexity) of loops, or, ways to improve it.

Let's take the following:

```
var pairs = 0;
HashSet<int> hs = new HashSet<int>(n);
for (var i = 0; i < ar.Length; i++)
{
    if(!hs.Contains(ar[i]))
        hs.Add(ar[i]);
    else
    {
        pairs++;
        hs.Remove(ar[i]);
    }
}

return pairs;
```

From what I can determine, the worst-case time-complexity of the above is: O(n), because of the loop.

Are the any way of improving this, to bring the time-complexity as close to O(1) as possible?

PS: I'm pretty sure that the the above will never be O(1).

Thank you

Comment: I think you need to be posting your question to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/
you also need to provide more clarification as to what your function is trying to achieve

Comment: what is`ar` ? also `if(!hs.Contains(ar[i]))`kinda resudent  becuase HashSet<T>.Add(T) Method returns true if the element is added to the HashSet<T> object; false if the element is already present.

Comment: @styx sorry, ar is an int array.

Comment: What exactly are the requirements.  It looks like the requirement starts with "look at each element of ar and then..."  there is no way to get less than O(n) if you have to look at each element to solve the problem.

Comment: You can't process n elements without processing n elements (duh), so O(n) is optimal.

Comment: Think about it this way. Your task is apparently to count pairs in an array -- which you should have said in the question. OK, how would you do that in real life? I take a deck of cards, remove a bunch of the cards, shuffle it, and hand you the cards. Your job is to count the pairs. Obviously you have to look at every card to do that task, so it will be at least O(number of cards)

Comment: As for ways to improve the program -- conceptually it is fine.  Some of the small details are somewhat weird though.  You declare an integer counter with `var`, but then repeat the type of the hash set in its declaration instead of using `var`, for instance. That is certainly not *wrong* but it looks sloppy, inconsistent and weird.

Comment: Or, I find it weird to write `if(!x) foo else bar` when you could write the simpler `if (x) bar else foo`.  Little details like that make a program harder to read and understand.

Comment: @Hogan that’s exactly what I was looking for... nothing complex, just other opinions as to whether it’s possible or not... better to ask a question then assuming.

Comment: Thanks everyone...

Comment: Or, there is no reason to write a for loop here. `foreach(int item in ar) if (hs.Contains(item)) …` would be conceptually easier to follow, since the loop variable in your program is *only* used for indexing.

Comment: @EricLippert Yeah, I know... it’s purely for illustration. It would defeat the purpose of the question if I had to include the whole solution.

Comment: Now, as for raw performance, there are things you can do to make this faster overall particularly if you know something about the range. Do you know for example that the integers are all between 0 and 100, for instance? If you know that then you can counting-sort the integers and then read the pairs out of the counts. But that only works if the integer range is small and the number of integers is relatively large.

Comment: @EricLippert thank you

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is more appropriate to codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Your code for counting pairs is wrong, could be seen as wrong.   say you have the numbers 2,2,2,  should there be only 1 pair here, since a pair consists of 2. 3 pairs here for each matching of pairs e.g if index[0,1][0,2][1,2]

Answer (score 0):

If you need to count pairs like this across *n* items, by definition you cannot do better than O(*n*) because you need to look at each item. Just iterating through the items is O(*n*) and any item may be part of a pair so you need to iterate through them all.

That is, unless you are dealing with some special case in which it is possible to figure out how many pairs there has to be by the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle), if the items may have only *m* unique values and *m* < *n*. Say you have 5 items and each item can only be "A" or "B" then you know there are going to two pairs without even looking at the items; the time complexity of coming up with 2 is O(1). This is the only situation in which I can see you getting better formal time complexity.